# image flickering on mouseover even when sprites are used for hover image

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a website: [parisforaweekend.com](http://www.parisforaweekend.com) with a 'subscribe' button-image that changes color on mouseover. Both images are part of the same image sprite.

Still in Chrome (v. 15) I'm getting very noticeable, but irregular occurring,  flickering on mouse-over. How on earth is this possible?  Also tested on IE8 and FF6 which don't appear to have the problem. It annoys me a lot.

I guess the general question is has anybody seen something like this before? Anything that can explain this weird behavior?

Although I can't see what possible use it is I included the relevant css-snippet:

CSS

EDIT: changed order of css rules to reflect real situation (although I can't see that making a difference)

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
margin: -1px 0 10px 15px;
padding: 0;
border: 0 none;
cursor: pointer;
background: url('http://static.parisforaweekend.com/img/s.jpg') 0 0;
line-height: 32px;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.button:hover {
background: url('http://static.parisforaweekend.com/img/s.jpg') -101px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

EDIT: perhaps it has to do with the fact that I'm using S3 + cloudfront (Amazon's CDN). Not caching correctly (on Edge-location or on client) and doing 2 requests or something. Hmm, still pretty unlikely.

Comment: I must say, im using v. 15 (specifically 15.0.874.106), and i see no flickering.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flickering." The button looks exactly the same on my Chrome 15 and Firefox 7. I _do_ notice that your button's regular state and hover state image seem to have _slightly_ different widths, causing the button to appear to shift on hover. You'd have to go back to the image editor to fix this.

Comment: with flickering I meant that, sometimes, the button vanishes on mouseover and it can take up to say half a second to appear in the hover-state.  I checked a couple of minutes ago, and I must say I don't see the flickering now either.. hmmm . Thanks for checking anyway

Comment: Very odd. I just encountered the same phenomenon on a website I'm working on. Looking at the network tab in Chrome, it seems the sprite is fetched twice - once during initial page rending ... and when I mouse over the image, the entire sprite is re-fetched by Chrome. Smells like a bug. My css is generated automatically so it's hard for me not to include background-image on the :hover style ... but I think I'll write a script that removes background-image property from all :hover styles.

Comment: The problem does not reproduce any more (on Chrome 15.0.874.106)... I suspect Google pushed an update to Chrome that fixed it.

Comment: thanks for confirming I wasn't loosing my mind :)

Comment: See the new comment I posted on my answer ... there is some serious voodoo at work here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using background-position instead of background?
I'm not seeing the problem you mentioned either, but it may be something to do with essentially redefining the background image on hover.

Comment: updated it. Not seeing it anymore at this time. I'll accept when I try later today a couple of times to see if the problem doesn't return. (after all it was irregular) .. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
a.btndownload{background-image:url(../images/btn-download-sprite.gif); background-position:left top; background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block;}
a.btndownload:link{background-position: left top;}
a.btndownload:visited{background-position: left top;}
a.btndownload:hover{background-position:  0px -34px;}
a.btndownload:active{background-position:  bottom left;}
```

Above is the sample code that solves the image flickering problem when using image sprite.

DO NOT OVERWRITE IMAGE URL again and again, even if it's same as the first one.
OTHERWISE it'd give Chrome false signal to load the same image over and over.

This problem emerges on Chrome 18 again. Other browsers like IE 9 and Firefox are fine.

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads the first background image is loaded automatically. When you then mouse over it has to then **retrieve** the second image causing a slight delay. The irregularity you mention is then based on caching. If the image is cached then you wont get a flicker.

To resolve have the images side by side in the **same .jpg**. Then use the background-position to set the image you want.

The image will no longer have to be retrieved and this will prevent your flicker.

Comment: what you suggest are the image sprites I'm talking about. As you can see in the supplied css I'm already doing that. Thanks

Comment: Ah apologies, I saw the two background css rules and didnt notice they were the same image.

Comment: no probs. Probably because I should have defined background-position instead to make it clearer only the position changes. That's probably the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the flicker occurs on Chrome but you should not set background image url for hover pseudo class, only change the background position. Please try this

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button:hover {
    background-position: -101px 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's probably it. I'll accept Alan's answer above because it was sooner :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this question by Googling for the same problem on my site. Given the timing (this was asked yesterday), I would assume that this a new bug that a recent Chrome version introduced in the caching mechanism.

As mentioned in other answers, removing the background-image from other images should resolve the issue. I'm using Smart Sprites to generate the sprites, so I can't easily remove it (it gets inserted automatically), but I think I'll have to write a post-build script to do it, I don't see another solution.

Comment: Now the issue does not reproduce (Chrome 15.0.874.106)

Comment: And ... the issue comes back again. It's weird, I have two versions (X & X+1) of my site that have identical css and only minor/irrelevant changes. When I switch to X+1 version, the problem appears, while on version X it does not happen. This can't be a cache issue, since I'm clearing caches between my tests ... extremely weird.

Comment: I'd go with the post-build script as you suggest and get it over with. It's clearly some weird bug at play, no use to break your head over it

Comment: Nice, might be of use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. But in my case it was caused by some other rule. Setting the CSS3 transition to 0 did the trick:

```
-webkit-transition: 0s;
-moz-transition:    0s;
-o-transition:      0s;
```